# Parameters Hidden or not in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012, ssrs-2008-r2

In SSRS, we  have parameters and also DataSets in Report Data. I want to know whether or which  parameters are hidden or not ( hide if it is any database key field ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few ways to see parameter settings in SSRS.

1. You can view them on the SSRS site by clicking on the report
   drop down and going to manage then parameters. This has a limited amount of information about the parameters but will show if they are hidden or not.
2. If you want more information on the parameters open the report in
   visual studio. Expand parameters in the report data pane. You should
   see a list of your parameters. Just right click on one and click
   parameter properties. This will give you everything configured for
   that parameter.